# Web.config - Rewrite rule for redirecting with multiple queries in one URI

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

I have this issue where I want to redirect domain.com/profile.php?user=username&page=1

I have a rule for just redirecting to the user query but when I use the following rule in the web.config for both queries I get server error 500. Is there any wrongs in my rule?

```
<rule name="rule 2Q">
     <match url="^profile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)"  />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/profile.php?user={R:1}&page={R:2}"  />
</rule>
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that the link I want to enter in the web browser is domain.com/profile/[username]/[pageid]

but the webserver should process this as domain.com/profile.php?user=username&page=1

Comment: It might help to show the source and the destination urls. You say you want to direct `domain.com/profile.php?user=username&page=1` but you don't say if this is the url coming from the browser or the url you want the web server to process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which regex parser your web server uses, however, I would suggest something (PCRE compatible) might be more appropriate, `/^profile\/(.+)\/(.+)/`. If the url contains more variants than you describe then maybe a less greedy regex expression might be in order.

Comment: Tried it but with the same result

Comment: As per my response above, can you confirm which web server you are using? Also, the addition of your edit means there is no trailing `/` so you might try and modify my regex to `/^profile\/(.+)\/(.+)`, although this is not materially different from your regex so the fault may lie in the other config such as the `action` element.

Comment: I'm using IIS 8, the regex was never an issue when I had the application on an Apache server with htaccess, so I guess it's something with IIS 8 that's different

Comment: Having had a quick look at the [documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) it appears that your config looks broadly right. I guess the next logical steps are to ask; 1) are you sure all the components are installed? The documentation mentions ASP.Net role service. 2) have you looked at the server logs for any errors? 3) have you tried using the test page as per their example which documents some of the variables for you. Finally are you sure you have restarted IIS fully. I known it's very funny with config changes.